# Windows.onload и $(windows).load() бесконечен ибо не срабатывает для мобильной версии

Tags: javascript, reactjs

На пк все норм, после загрузки сраницы полностью прелоадер, который находится в функции windows.onload, исчезает, что явяется хорошим результатом, а в мобильных версиях прелоадер бесконечен. Приложение работает на ReactJS, в курсе что есть подобные библиотеки и готовые решения через npm, но нужно именно чисто js способ.

```
<div class="preloader">LOADING...</div>

.preloader {
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
background: #e0e0e0;
z-index: 9999;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

}

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden'; // preloader
window.onload = function () {
    document.body.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    $('.preloader').fadeOut();
}
```

Comment: `$('.preloader').fadeOut()` — это не «чисто js» способ, это уже jQuery

Comment: О каких «мобильных версиях» речь? Как вы проверили, что «прелоадер бесконечен», может у вас просто не хватило терпения дождаться загрузки? Какие ошибки в браузерной консоли?

Comment: Во первых в реакте крайне не рекомендуется обращаться к document элементу, это ломает всю его работу, про JQuery я вообще молчу

Comment: Во вторых почитай про React хуки, а в частности про useEffect(), и будет тебе счастье